# Format input date nest.js typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I have date in input in nest.js in api request body. Can i set custom format for input?
Ex 12.12.2022

````
  @ApiProperty({
    example: 'ADMIN',
    description: 'Имя роли',
  })
  readonly value: string;
  @ApiProperty({
    example: 1,
    description: 'Id пользователя',
  })
  readonly id: number;
  @ApiProperty({
    example: Date.now(),
    description: 'Дата исхода роли',
  })
  readonly expireDate?: Date;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your answer should be found here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator#user-content-validation-decorators

As I see it, you have either `@IsDateString()` or make a custom one with `@IsDate()`.
If this doesnt support the date format you need, then your option would be to do a custom validator. See a thread about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70907953/class-validator-node-js-get-another-property-value-within-custom-validation).

Good luck!